# inexplicable error : java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am iterating through an array of objects and I do not modify the objects.
Why Do I get the following error?

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Code:

```
ArrayList<Event> events=HistoryData.getEvents();

for (Event event: events) { <----- Getting the error here
  HistoryDate eventDate = event.getEventDate();

  if (eventDate.isGreaterEqualThen(searchDate)) {
    ActualDate.setDate(event.getEventDate());

    break;
  }
}
```

***UPDATE***

I have a Thread that Loads the Array, then I call a handler at the end of the thread. At that time, the array is already loaded.
In this handler I am accessing the Array as the code shows. Is this prerunning Thread the problem ?

Comment: you are in a multithread app right?

Comment: paste the full code snippet ?... Seems this code will work . I need to know, how this code is linked ?

Answer (score 2):

[Concurrent Modification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) errors are thrown when the same data set is changed by two different operations at the same time.

It happens when multi-threading: something on a background thread has added, removed or changed position of an item in your list, before you finish looping through the list

Comment: Yep, I bet the list returned by the static method `HistoryData.getEvents()` is being modified in another thread.

Comment: I have a Thread that Loads the Array, then I call a handler at the end of the thread. In this handler I am accessing the Array as the code shows. Is then the Thread the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Another thread is accessing your thread-unsafe list or you're trying to modify the list within the loop so the code breaks when you want to iterate using the next element. If it's another thread, then perhaps you could change you list type to [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) or lock the list by adding synchronized statement, but nevertheless, don't change the list within that. loop.

```
synchronized (events) {
    for (Event event: events) {
        HistoryDate eventDate = event.getEventDate();

        if (eventDate.isGreaterEqualThen(searchDate)) {
            ActualDate.setDate(event.getEventDate());

            break;
        }
    }
}
```